Simple proposition leading to the formula of change of variables formula for multiple integrals
I was reading an article on the change of variables formula for multiple integrals (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X01977959/pdf?md5=f5e26931f2b96d2dc05bdc18c6553356&pid=1-s2.0-S0022247X01977959-main.pdf), but I couldn't understand how to derive theorem $1.1$ from theorem $1.2$ as shown below. The article doesn't provide an explanation, and I couldn't figure it out myself. In particular, I'm having trouble understanding how to handle the absolute value of $|\det D\phi(x)|$. I would appreciate it if someone could explain this, ideally using concepts  from calculus to elementary measure theory or differential forms.
$ Theorem\;1.1$
Let $U$ and $\Omega$ be open sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $\phi : U\rightarrow \Omega$ be a $C^1$ diffeomorphism. If $f$ is continuous on $\Omega$ with compact support, then the following holds:
$$
\int_{U} f(\phi(x))|\det D\phi(x)|dx = \int_{\Omega} f(x)dx.
$$
$Theorem\;1.2$
Let $\phi : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a $C^1$ map. Assume that $x \rightarrow \phi(x) = x$ for $|x| \geq R$. If $f$ is a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}^n$ with compact support, then the following holds:
$$
\int f(\phi(x)) \det D\phi(x) dx = \int f(x) dx.
$$
